# How to send large post string data via WebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm sending the content of the file via post request using WebRequest.

It is working fine when the file has less content but it is not sending any data when the content is large.

```cs
WebRequest HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://testapi.com");

HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
HttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", APIKEY);

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

HttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
HttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream requestStream = HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();  

requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

I'm getting the empty array at the API end. It should get all the file content that I'm sending.

I tried with postman and it worked fine. So I think the issue is in c# side.

Comment: Have you verified that you have to send your data as `x-www-form-urlencoded`? What kind of data is the service expecting, when url-encoded? Maybe just the security token activation/validation.

Comment: I think everything else is fine as if I remove some content from my post data the request will be successful. So it seems to me that the main issue is the large content of post data. So I don't think it's related to security token or any other post parameter.

Comment: With `x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type, you usually send Url-Encoded (see [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode), for example) key-value pairs to a service. Did you Url-Encode the data? Maybe try with HttpClient's [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent) that does the job for you (white spaces are encoded using `+` instead of `%20` in this case). What kind of data are you sending?

Comment: yes, the issue was because of encoding. When encoded the entire data two times it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a big file, first of all you have to encode it:

```
StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file =
new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
fileContents.Append( WebUtility.UrlEncod(line)+ '%0A');
}

file.Close();
```

after that

```
         Uri uri = new Uri("http://testapi.com");
         using(WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
         {
           myWebClient.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY",APIKEY);
           myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form- urlencoded");

           string result = myWebClient.UploadString(uri ,"plu_str="+fileContents.ToString());
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've one doubt here. After sending the post data we will get some json response. Depending on that response we perform some actions.
Is there any way to get the response which we can process further? Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks for the update. I also found that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddata?view=netframework-4.8

But unfortunately, that didn't help. I'm getting the same response as I was getting with  WebRequest. 

Is there any other way that I can send a request by dividing the content into chunks. 
I found a solution for reading the response stream in chunks but not found anything like that for requests.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough in describing the issue as I'm not much experienced with c#

Comment: And also may be you send wrong encoding bytes, try Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes.

Comment: it is working from postman so the issue there. If I post the same content from postman it will work fine and processed at the API end. 
But if I send the same content via my c# code. It will show an empty array at the other end.
Tried changing the encoding to ASCII got the same result.

Comment: Can you give remote access? Anydesk or TeamViewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200718/discussion-between-oleg-and-mohit).